# Using TF command-line get latest, how do I run SonarQube analysis only if new code has been checked-in?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, tfs, sonarqube

I use a BAT file to run TF command-line get latest and then call the Sonar runner BAT file to run analysis on the latest code.
I have automated this every hour using Task Scheduler.
I want to run Sonar analysis only if TF gets new code, else it should skip.

How do I achieve this? I tried searching for exit codes, but nothing tells me if any new code was fetched.

Answer (score 2):

**Visual Studio Team Services or TFS 2015+**

You can configure a build to be triggered on Continuous Integration (CI), i.e. whenever changes are made, the build is triggered. A build can be whatever you want, from invoking a proper msbuild / mstest and SonarQube task or doing your own stuff using cmd / powershell / bash.

To learn more about integrating SonarQube analysis with TFS Build see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/08/24/build-tasks-for-sonarqube-analysis/

**TFS 2013**

You can configure a XAML build to run on Continous Integration

**Through scripts**

Continous Integration builds are the recommended way of running logic when a change happens in your code. However, if you'd like to use "tf get" - you could capture the output of "tf get" and if it matches "All files are up to date" then do nothing, else trigger the SonarQube execution.

Comment: Thanks a lot @bogdan-gavril-msft. Will try through scripts first. The ultimate plan is still to integrate it to CI, which will come after this is successful.

Comment: Also, @bogdan can you kindly point me to a good article which describes the CI integration of SonarQube?

Comment: Hi @AhmadZaib - what build system are you using? Team Build (aka XAML build|) or the new TFS Build (available with TFS 2015+ or with the service offering), or something non-Microsoft?

Comment: Hi @Bogdan, we have recently migrated to TFS 2015. So we look forward to integrating Sonar in the same. Thanks for taking your time to help us out :)

Comment: Hi @Bogdan, any leads on the above? We are using TFS 2015 now.

Comment: Hi @AhmadZaib - I updated my answer with a link to a blog post that will guide you. Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks @Bogdan, we will try to follow the guide. Will get in touch if we face any problems :)